# How to eliminate "ghost" folders and files?

Tags: filesystem, ntfs, delete

I have folders and files on the external HD (ntfs) that do not want to be eliminated.

From Shell I can't view them actually but in Dolphin they are present.
They are annoying because they are there in the middle and they have no good use.

I tried to eliminate them by selecting them and pressing "Canc", and it say me "the file xy doesen't not exist".
I also tried from Shell with `rm -R foldername`, but nothing worked.

```
rm: cannot remove 'eso/personale': Input/output error
```

There is a solution? Thanks

Comment: `RM -R` for sure cannot work. Connect that drive to a Windows machine and have it thorughly checked and repaired using the WIndows checking tools. Then properly disconnect from the windows system before connecting to Ubuntu. You will then be able to delete them.

Comment: It never been connected to windows

Comment: When using ntfs you would need windows to repair a disk filesystem. That way you can safely conclude if the disk is damaged. I would suggest to copy the file from the disk, format it and put the file back if you only have Ubuntu.